# Following RAM upgrading, why the rate of memory used remained almost same?

Tags: memory

After I upgraded the memory on my laptop (from 8 GB to 16 GB) without changing any other hardwares or softwares, the rate of usage of memory remained the same, and the memory used increased almost proportionally to the size of new memory.

Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why is my RAM being used on absolutely nothing?](https://superuser.com/q/1788109/241386)

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the memory cache of Windows in action.
The size of this cache is calculated by Windows as a percentage of the
total RAM.

The memory in the cache is immediately available for usage by programs,
if needed. It is not lost memory, but contains files or
programs that were read from disk, and are kept in memory
for performance in case that they would be needed again.