# Why am I using 2.6gb of memory even though no apps are on

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I tried everything to make it go down by following Youtube videos, suggestions on google, etc, but it still doesn't work. Only thing that managed to work was downloading Wise Memory Optimizer which did help.

And when I go to Task manager > Users, I see that I only use 200mb-ish (no apps, basically idle) and when I go to performance, I see 2.5gb is in use, why?

Note that I have 4gb ram

Comment: Why doest it matter?

Comment: Empty RAM is wasted RAM. Let the system do its job.

Comment: well, my laptop is old and been really slow, I thought this would be the reason why.

Comment: System processes use memory too, so the users tab is useless

Comment: duplicate: [Why is my RAM being used on absolutely nothing?](https://superuser.com/q/1788109/241386). Hint: it's used for useful things